# log statement in button callback displays undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

on the below posted exmaple, I am trying to log the number of the button. but when i clcik any button e.target.i displays undefined??!!
I am using sandbox

please let me know how to fix this issue.

**code**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

class ButtonClicks extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this);
  }

  onClickFunction(e) {
    console.log("button# " + e.target.id);
  }

  render() {
    var arrButtons = [];
    var buttonStyle = {
      margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      //Moved your loop outside render()'s return
      arrButtons.push(
        <button
          id={i}
          style={buttonStyle}
          onClick={() => this.onClickFunction()}
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons} {/*Very important to wrap the buttons inside a div*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClicks />, rootElement);
export default ButtonClicks;
```

Comment: You could just write `onClick={this.onClickFunction}` and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

When you use arrow function syntax, the arguments passed to the function when it is called need to passed explicitly like

```
arrButtons.push(
    <button
      id={i}
      style={buttonStyle}
      onClick={(e) => this.onClickFunction(e)}
    >
      {i}
    </button>
  );
```

However a better way of doing it is to use the arrow function outside of render, however since you already do it in the constructor, you don't even need to use the arrow function syntax.

```
onClickFunction = (e) => {
    console.log("button# " + e.target.id);
  }

  render() {
    var arrButtons = [];
    var buttonStyle = {
      margin: "10px 10px 10px 0"
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      //Moved your loop outside render()'s return
      arrButtons.push(
        <button
          id={i}
          style={buttonStyle}
          onClick={this.onClickFunction}
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {arrButtons} {/*Very important to wrap the buttons inside a div*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
```